# mondgo db does not save with large documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm iterating over a an object with 10000 key/val pairs and creating 'gameItem' docs and adding them to my 'items' field as a hash object and then saving them to my mongo collection like so.

Here's my main collection

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var myItemDbSchema = new Schema({
    db_num: Number,
    last_updated: Number,
    items: {type: {}, default: {}}
}, { minimize: false });

module.exports = mongoose.model('myItemDb', myItemDbSchema);
```

and then my logic

```
PartnerAPI.getItems(function(err, partnerItems){

    myItemDb.findOne({"db_num": 1}, function(myItemDB){

        for(var partnerItem in partnerItems){

            if(!myItemDB.items[partnerItem]){

                var newItem = new gameItem({
                    name: partnerItems[partnerItem].name
                });

                myItemDB.items[partnerItem] = newItem;
            }

            myItemDB.markModified('items');

            myItemDB.save(function(err){
                logger.info("Saved");
            });
        }

    });
});
```

partner items looks like this

```
{
    'ballistic-weapon-1':{name:'bl1', value:'rare'}
},
{
    'ballistic-weapon-2':{name:'bl2', value:'rare'}
}
```

This works fine if I only add no more than 300 to the items field and then mark items as modified and then save... but if I try to add all 10,000 and try to save - they don't. Is there a size limit for how many docs I can add to a field with a type {}?

Is there a better way to save these docs without having to write some logic to limit how many saves I do each iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 16mb document limit. So if your document (BSON) is larger than 16 mb, mongodb throws exception.

docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!